# How to count characters from nested lists of strings inside a dictionary (Python)?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I'm trying to count the frequency of a charater from nested lists of strings inside a dictionary.
Returning, for each key, the most frequent value.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
res = {0: ['a', 'a', 'b'], 1: ['e'], 2: ['i', 'x', 'i', 'c']}
for k, v in res.items():
    # count the most frequent
print(res)
```

Expecting:

```
res = {0: 'a', 1: 'e', 2: 'i'}
```

Comment: what about this doesn't work? you may just need to create a second dict to pack your results into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = {k: most_frequenct(v) for k, v in data.items()}
```

most_frequenct could be any of the following
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-most-frequent-element-in-a-list/

Hope it helps